# How to manage in edit items already selected

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

I have a select2, which lists all items of a database table. One of these items is already selected. In edit mode, how can I show the already selected item and list the rest of the items?

**IN CONTROLLER:**

```
$offertaheader = Offertaheader::find($id_offertaheader);
$clients = Client::all()->where('visibility',1)
                        ->sortBy('nome');
return view('offertas.edit',compact('offertaheader','clients'));
```

**IN VIEW BLADE:**

```html
<select class="form-control select2" name="id_cliente" style="width: 100%">
  <optgroup label="<?php echo htmlentities(utf8_encode('CLIENTE'), 0, "UTF-8"); ?>">
    <option></option>
    @foreach($clients as $client)
    <option value="{{$client->id}}" {{ (old('id_client', $client->id) == ($client ? $client->id : '') ? ' selected' : '') }}>{{$client->nome}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I want that the already selected item must be shown and at the same time the user can change it in the blade. I prefer to avoid front-end codings like jquery or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can update using sync method, sth like this,

```
public function upate()
{
    $todo = Todo::findOrFail($id);
    $data = $request->all();
    $todo->update($data);
    $users = $request->users;
    $users = User::find($users);
    $todo->users()->sync($users);
    return response()->json("success",200);
}
```